# Failing to use system() and win 10 bash.exe in Matlab

Tags: bash, matlab, cmd, windows-10

I am trying to use the new bash functionally of windows 10 to run a linux program through matlab.

In this particular case it's a program called snaphu that processes an inputfile and generates an outputfile. In linux (or the new bash shell in win10) you would run it like:

```
snaphu -f configfile inputfile
```

You can run this command directly in cmd by:

```
bash -c "snaphu -f configfile inputfile"
```

This processes the file and generates an output file.
I use matlab to make the inputfile and I would like to run snaphu after making that file by using

```
system('bash -c "snaphu -f configfile inputfile"')
```

to use matlab to process the output file it generates in one work flow. However using this command I don't get my output file. Appending & does work, however.

```
system('bash -c "snaphu -f configfile inputfile" &')
```

The problem with this approach is that I am using a for loop to process roughly 1000 of these inputfiles, each different from the last iteration. If I use the "&" it opens up a new window every time.

I don't understand why it does generate the output file in the latter case, but not the first. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I've had the same problem with MATLAB's `system` command in Linux too. That the ampersand makes it work is a big hint. Can you find a way to back ground a process without popping up a terminal? If you know what files you will need to run on, you could try making a command that runs snaphu on each of them. Then you only get one terminal?? Not ideal, but a possible work around.

Comment: I added '& exit' to the system command, which closes the cmd window. Currently I am using a while loop to make sure matlab continues only when the outputfile is created. It's a decent work around. Tbh, I would like an option where I can make matlab addres bash.exe directly.

Comment: Windows's `bash` is pretty picky when it comes to terminal windows for stdio, so opening a window to make it work seems to make sense. (bad idea alert) perhaps running an `sshd` on the bash-on-windows side can save you some windows?

Comment: Dear Sir, your problem is that you have to modify the shell script to process all files with only one call, not in a loop from outside. This is my view, and I don't know who is going to agree. In fact, this is how I see it : snaphu -f configfile inputfileS